# How do i learn this animation in canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

i found this web convnet.js and it has this gui animation for neural network, where the background color will try to covered circle with the same color, where can i learn this or what do you guys call this , i'm confused , i don't even know what to type in google[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyE0C.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The animation that you mention, found in the ConvNetJS site, is created using the Canvas API: A Web technology used to draw and animate graphics in all modern browsers.

You can find more information in the following links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

The code responsible for the animation you mention, can be found in the web page source: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/npgmain.js

So, if you want to learn more, you can google for `Canvas API` or `HTML5 Canvas`.

[Canvas API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#New_APIs) was introduced with HTML version 5.